# Get table content from specific website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello i found this [WEBSITE](http://fr.investing.com/commodities/#dailyTab)  and i want to get content of table and publish it in my website...is there any way to do it  with javascript or php (without ifram or object)

Comment: It's not the correct things to grab the data from any other site , however you can achive that by PHP Curl or make the grabber and grab the data.

Comment: Which table? There are multiple ones, and you said 'table', as a singular object.

Comment: @JohnnyBell this table "Performance Table"

Comment: Check Hardik's answer below. But as it's been mentioned, I'd implore you to check the legal conditions of that website. You may not have permission to replicate anything they produce on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code can help you

```
$html=getHTML("http://www.website.com",10);
preg_match("/<title>(.*)</title>/i", $html, $match);
$title = $match[1];

//use curl to get html content
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}
$html=getHTML("http://www.website.com",10);
// Find all images on webpage
foreach($html->find("img") as $element)
echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links on webpage
foreach($html->find("a") as $element)
echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: can you help me to use this example in my case because it didn't work for  me